# In .net how can i make a own Login + Register (hashing + salt)?

Tags: .net, authentication, salt

i would like to make a own Login + Register in .net.

The Register should hash the password and also add salt to it.

How could i make this without using identity?

- It should hash a password in the register
- it should be possible to verify user , using the same hashing method
- and extra Salt should be used

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, I recommend to read the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article to learn more about how to ask a good question we can answer including a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

After searching i found it -> for further Users here is it how it can work:
The Register with hashing and salt:

```
const int HASH_SIZE = 32;
const int iterations = 35000;
HashAlgorithmName algorithm = HashAlgorithmName.SHA512;

public async void createNewUser()
{

        uSalt = RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(HASH_SIZE);

        string hashedPassword = HashPassword(uPass, uSalt);

        User user = new User
            {
                FirstName = uFirst,
                LastName = uLast,
                Email = uEmail,
                Password = hashedPassword,
                Salt = uSalt,
            };

        await userservice.AddUserAsync(user);
        NavManager.NavigateTo("/");
    }
  

public string HashPassword(string password, byte[] salt)
{
    var hash = Rfc2898DeriveBytes.Pbkdf2(
      Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password),
      salt,
      iterations,
      algorithm,
      HASH_SIZE
      );

    return Convert.ToHexString(hash);
}
```

And heres the Login = verify:

```
const int HASH_SIZE = 32;
const int iterations = 35000;
HashAlgorithmName algorithm = HashAlgorithmName.SHA512;

public async void login()
{

    User user = await userservice.GetUserAsync(Username);
    if (user != null)
    {
        bool isValid = VerifyPassword(Password, user.Password, user.Salt);
        if (isValid)
        {
            NavManager.NavigateTo(($"/MyRecipts/{user.FirstName}/{user.LastName}/{user.Id}"));
        }
        else
        {
            LoginWentWrong = true;
        }
    }
}

public bool VerifyPassword(string password, string hash, byte[] salt)
{
    var hashToCompare = Rfc2898DeriveBytes.Pbkdf2(password,
        salt,
        iterations,
        algorithm,
        HASH_SIZE);

    return CryptographicOperations.FixedTimeEquals(hashToCompare, Convert.FromHexString(hash));
}
```

Dont forget to add the Salt to the User Class as this Type:

```
        public required byte[] Salt { get; set; }   //save the Salt in the DB -> so it can be used again for verifying the user
```

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to roll your own security. Well engineered systems get hacked.

Comment: So would it be better to use Identity instead? Or would you recommend another Login Service?

Comment: @MogliMehmet These questions are really not suitable for a Q&A site like stack overflow since they are highly opinion based and depend a lot on your use case and requirements.

Comment: @MogliMehmet - I can't recommend any log in service, but I do suggest that you don't write your own. Someone can just rewrite your `VerifyPassword` method's assembly to be `public bool VerifyPassword(string password, string hash, byte[] salt) => true;` and your code just logs in no matter what.